# A command for a perfect justify / formatting on Linux

Tags: text-formatting

I have a text like this

```
Transport Layer Security (TLS) and its predecessor 
Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
 are cryptographic presentation protocols used in the telecommunications field
```

I want a "perfect" formatting like this

```
 Transport Layer Security (TLS) and its predecessor Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
 are cryptographic presentation protocols used in the telecommunications field
```

is not important the "grammar standards"

this example is also ok

```
 Transport Layer Security (TLS) and its predecessor Secure Sockets Layer (SSL
 ) are cryptographic presentation protocols used in the telecommunications fi
 eld
```

I have tried the commands

```
fmt -w 77
```

and

```
par
```

but the result is not that I want.
Any suggestion?
I usually use vim, so even vim commands are accepted, but better with an external command to use with any editor or without editor.
With vim i have tried this method

```
set formatprg=par\ j1w77
```

and
then `gq`, but the result is not what I want.

Comment: Have you tried `gq}` from the first line of the paragraph (or [any motion with `gq`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html?#gq)  really)?

Comment: Sure, but the result is bad

Comment: Running `gq` with `formatprg` set to `par` is no different from just running `par` directly.

Comment: @steeldriver that's the thing, Vim by default will happily chew through newlines, use spaces to join lines and provide the second code block after running `gq` on the first. But OP seems to insist on using external commands.

Comment: You must have some setting in your PARINIT variable which is doing that because `par j1w77` without a defined PARINIT variable produces your "perfect formatting" output (and does a pretty good job even with no options).  BTW, I have `PARINIT="rTbgqR B=.,?_A_a Q=_s>| w78"` which works just fine with your sample input....I have no idea exactly what those par options do because I haven't even looked at the par documentation since the mid 1990s. I set it like that for reformatting quoted email, and it's done what I wanted ever since.  I rarely override it do more than change the width setting.

Comment: The export PARINIT variable solution is perfect. If you add this as an answer I can vote and close the question, thanks.

Comment: You showed 2 examples of acceptable output but didn't show or tell us what would be unacceptable output so it's a guess what you'd consider "perfect".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in the comment of the user cas

```
export PARINIT="rTbgqR B=.,?_A_a Q=_s>| w78"
```

this if you want to "cut" after char number 78
then open vim, select text and press `gq`.
Works fine.